# Hive CASE WHEN THEN ISSUE

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, php-ziparchive

Below is the code failing in Hive:

> (Alias at 6:5 (END) is not recognized)

```
INSERT INTO WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONE_RECLASS
select
case
when WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONENT_FINAL.REVENUE_FLAG != 'Y'
AND WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONENT_FINAL.EXCLUDED_FLAG = 'Y'
THEN WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONE_RECLASS.EXECUTION_ORDER = '1'
END
FROM WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONENT_FINAL
```

Comment: Does Hive require a column alias? Try like `END AS EXECUTION_ORDER` or something.

Comment: Also, you probably want an `ELSE` in there somewhere. `ELSE 0` perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I tried both the things but no success. I will update once it get resolved.

Comment: Do you want to insert a new row or update an existing one?

Comment: Code is running now:INSERT INTO WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONE_RECLASS(EXECUTION_ORDER)
select (case when WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONENT_FINAL.REVENUE_FLAG != 'Y'
AND WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONENT_FINAL.EXCLUDED_FLAG = 'Y'
THEN  '1'
END) AS EXECUTION_ORDER FROM WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONENT_FINAL

Answer (score 1):

this one: `THEN WRKT_REGULATORY_COMPONE_RECLASS.EXECUTION_ORDER = '1'` is wrong
after THEN it should be literal `1` or column